# MySQL primary/foreign key size?

Tags: mysql, size, primary-key, foreign-keys

I seem to see a lot of people arbitrarily assigning large sizes to primary/foreign key fields in their MySQL schemas, such as INT(11) and even BIGINT(20) as WordPress uses.

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but even an INT(4) would support (unsigned) values up to over 4 billion. Change it to INT(5) and you allow for values up to a quadrillion, which is more than you would ever need, unless possibly you're storing geodata at NASA/Google, which I'm sure most of us aren't.

Is there a reason people use such large sizes for their primary keys? Seems like a waste to me...

Comment: No, the size field is in characters not binary bytes. So int(4) can only hold up to 9999 (in theory; the database may store it internally as bigger). INT(11) is actually just a 32-bit number.

Comment: @MarkR No, `INT(4)` doesn't mean 4-characters. `INT`/`INTEGER` is the data type, which is [_always_ 4 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). The `(4)` after is just a hint for the [minumum display width](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) of the field.

Answer (score 11):

> The size is neither bits nor bytes.
>   It's just the display width, that is
>   used when the field has ZEROFILL
>   specified.

and

> INT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL] A
>   normal-size integer. The signed range
>   is -2147483648 to 2147483647. The
>   unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295.

See [this explanation](http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any good reason to use a number larger than 32-bit integer for indexing data in normal business-sized databases. Most of them have maybe millions of records (or that order of magnitude).

Comment: Neither does MySQL.  They use 32-bit integers for the INT data type.  The number in () has no bearing on the number of bits.